# Refreshing a rallychart

Tags: rally

I have a Rally SDK 2.0p5 app that displays a chart.  When the user selects an option, the data will be updated and I would like to refresh the chart.  But instead of redrawing, it will place a new chart beneath.  What is the proper syntax?

```
                // Configure and Add the chart
                this.add(
                    {
                        xtype: 'rallychart',
                        height: 400,
                        id: 'chart',
                        chartConfig: {
                            chart: {
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'My Chart',
                                align: 'center'
                            },
                            xAxis: [
                                {
                                    categories: ['M0','M1','M2','M3','M4','M5'],
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Interval'
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: yText
                                }
                            },
                            series: [ { type: 'column',
                                        name: yText,
                                        data: mCount } ],
                            plotOptions : {
                                column: {
                                    color: '#F00'
                                },
                                series : {
                                    animation : {
                                        duration : 2000,
                                        easing : 'swing'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the 1st chart before adding the new one.

```
redrawChart: function() {
    this.remove('#chart');
    this.add({...});
}
```

Comment: I have the id set as 'chart', and it works without the "#"

redrawChart: function() {
    this.remove('chart');
    this.add({...});
}

Answer (score 0):

It's often better to just update the chart in place. HighCharts is the charting library that's included in the App SDK. HighCharts will even animate your changes. Cool!!! Look [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart) for the list of methods that operate on charts. You can add series, change data, change axis limits, control the zoom, etc.