# Updating a chart with new data in App SDK 2.0

Tags: rally

I am using a chart to visualize data in a `TimeboxScopedApp`, and I want to update the data when scope changes. The more brute-force approach of using `remove()` then redrawing the chart as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416308) leaves me with an overlaid "Loading..." mask, but otherwise works. The natural approach of using the Highchart native `redraw()` method would be my preference, only I don't know how to access the actual Highchart object and not the App SDK wrapper.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
var chart = Ext.getCmp('componentQualityChart');
if (chart) {
    var chartCfg = chart.getChartConfig();
    chartCfg.xAxis.categories = components;
    chart.setChartConfig(chartCfg);
    chart.setChartData(data);
    chart.redraw(); // this doesn't work with the wrapper object
} else { // draw chart for the first time
```

How do I go about redrawing the chart with the new data?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming chart (componentQualityChart) is an instance of `Rally.ui.chart.Chart`, you can access the HighCharts instance like this:

```
var highcharts = chart.down('highchart').chart;

// Now you have access to the normal highcharts interface, so
// you could change the xAxis
highcharts.xAxis[0].setCategories([...], true);

// Or you could change the series data
highcharts.series[0].data.push({ ... });  //Add a new data point

// Or pretty much anything else highcharts lets you do
```

Comment: Coould you tell what is hicharts object here? Or, maybe give a JSFiddle example? Unfortunately, for me it doesn't work as chart.down('highchart').chart is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Using _unmask() removes the overlaid "Loading.." mask

```
if (this.down('#myChart')) {
    this.remove('myChart');
}
 this.add(
                    {
                        xtype: 'rallychart',
                        height: 400,
                        itemId: 'myChart',
                        chartConfig: {
                            //....
                        },            
                        chartData: {
                            categories: scheduleStateGroups, 
                            series: [ 
                                {   
                                    //...
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                );
        this.down('#myChart')._unmask();
```